# How does scatter plot works in plotly?

Tags: python, graph, plotly, scatter-plot, plotly-python

How does plotly plot a scatter plot? What is the logic behind it? If I have a NumPy array-like

```
import numpy as np
arr = np.array([[1,2,3,1,2,3,4],[1,1,1,1,1,-6,4],[0,0,0,0,0,0,4],[-3,-2,-1,1,2,3,4],[1,1,15,1,2,-999,4]])
```

and I am using the following code to plot the array:

```
import plotly.express as px
fig = px.scatter(arr, len(arr), width=1000, height=500)
fig.update_layout(xaxis_title='array value', yaxis_title='index')
fig.show()
```

it has the following values for each point(from top to bottom)

> (-999, index = 4) (3, index =3) (3, index =3) (0, index =2) (-6 index
> =1) (3, index =0)

I can understand the value of the index (or y-axis coordinates ) as they are the array's index going from 0 to 4 due to its length being 5. But how is the x coordinate defined?
Please can someone tell me this?

[image: Graph of the scatter plot for coordinate reference]

Comment: what are you aiming to print with all of those subarrays?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that if you look at the documentation, you can figure it out https://plotly.com/python/line-and-scatter/

Comment: @AlbertoSinigaglia I looked at the documentation but I can't understand it w.r.t. the array example I have shown above. In reality, I have a NumPy array of shape (10, 250) and its plotting points in a manner I can't decipher. So, if you have an understanding of what is happening in the example above, please do explain.

Comment: @AlbertoSinigaglia if it was just a simple plotting of x vs y then I know what's happening. But I want to know who is plotly taking an index eg 3, and points (-3,-2,-1,1,2,3,4) and plotting it to a single point. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Plotly converts the NumPy array to a Pandas Dataframe. So your first argument becomes a dataframe and your second argument is the 'x' kwarg or the name of the x column. len(arr) was 5 so you picked column '5'. If you leave out the 'y' kwarg, it will default to the index of the dataframe.

So your code is equivalent to this:

```py
import plotly.express as px
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

arr = np.array([[1,2,3,1,2,3,4],[1,1,1,1,1,-6,4],[0,0,0,0,0,0,4],[-3,-2,-1,1,2,3,4],[1,1,15,1,2,-999,4]])

df = pd.DataFrame(arr)
df
```

[image]

```py
fig = px.scatter(df, x=5, y=None, width=1000, height=500)
fig.update_layout(xaxis_title='Column: 5')
fig.show()
```

I recommend you use Pandas with Plotly Express. Maybe do something like this instead.

```py
# name your columns
df.columns = ['var_a','var_b','speed', 'time','whatever','example','lastcolumn']

# specify the columns to plot on the x and y and any other kwargs you want.
fig = px.scatter(df, x='var_a', y='example', size='whatever', width=1000, height=500)
fig.show()
```

Comment: So, it's basically taking the len argument (5 as in question) and giving that value's respective column from the pd dataframe. Got it thanks a lot! I have been plotting just one column of the dataframe then. Is there a better way to do it?

Comment: Plotly express is more intuitive using Pandas (it converts it to a Pandas dataframe anyway). I will expand the answer to suggest a way you probably should use plotly express